# How to change the border color as gradient color

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using pin_code_fields: ^7.4.0 using this package can we change the border color as gradient color

Sample Code:

```
    child: PinCodeTextField(
                appContext: context,
                controller: _otpField,
                length: 6,
                onChanged: (value){
                  print(value);
                },
                pinTheme: PinTheme(
                  activeColor: AppColors.grayishBlue,
                  inactiveColor: AppColors.grayishBlue,
                  shape: PinCodeFieldShape.box,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  fieldHeight: SDP.sdp(33),
                  fieldWidth: SDP.sdp(38),
                  activeFillColor: Colors.white,
                )
              ),
```